# Appear my media player when any video is played from gallery or file explorer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using the following code in manifest but it is not working.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Videoplay"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />

            <!-- <data android:mimeType="*/*"></data> -->
            <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.mp3" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.ogg" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.wav" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.wma" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.flac"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.mp4"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\.mkv" />





        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Help me, what's going wrong because my app is not showing in the video intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below `intent-filter`:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: but this is for browser app not for a media player

Comment: i am making a video player

Comment: Ok. Update you soon

Comment: one issue is there

Comment: when i play a video from file manager then its work fine . but when any video is played from gallery then it play in the video player of gallery

Comment: how to handle this

Comment: go to apps -> galley-> clear default. Then it will work

Comment: can we do it programticaly that clear the default of gallery

Comment: that cannot be done programmatically. You have to do it manually